# Why did my form start requiring a double click to submit after I added the jquery validation plug in? How do I change it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a submit() event attached to my form submit button, before I started using the jquery validation plug in I could submit this form on a single click. Now for some reason it takes a second click. How can I make it go back to single click?

```
$("form").submit(function(){

    $(".selector").validate({


          rules: {
                   performance : {
                           required: true

                           //customvalidation: true
                   },
                   location : {
                           required: true

                           //customvalidation: true
                   },
                   date : {
                           required: true

                           //customvalidation: true
                   }
           },
           messages: {

                   performance : {
                           required: "enter a show name"

                           //customvalidation: true
                   },
                   location : {
                           required: "enter a location"

                           //customvalidation: true
                   },
                   date : {
                           required: "pick a date"

                           //customvalidation: true
                   }
           }

return false;

}); //closes submit()        


});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your whole problem...

```
$("form").submit(function(){

    $(".selector").validate({
        ...
```

You do not need to put `.validate()` inside of a `submit` event handler.  The plugin already captures the `submit` event automatically.  The `.validate()` method is the *initialization* method of the plugin on your form; it only gets attached to the `form` element and then only called *once* on DOM ready.  (You presently need to double-click because it takes the first click just to initialize the plugin.)

Just do this instead...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    ("#yourform").validate({
        // options & rules
    });

});
```

**Simple DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/x6Ckg/

If, for whatever reason, you need to run other code on the `submit` event, you would use the `submitHandler` callback function provided by the plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    ("#yourform").validate({
        //options & rules,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            // stuff to do when form is valid
            // ajax, etc?
        }
    });

});
```