# why won't jquery form validation work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that opens up inside of a dialog after a click event. I'm wondering if there is a syntax problem in my jquery that I'm not noticing. None of the logs in the submit handler function are logging.

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Thanks For Volunteering">
     <form>
         <p>Please provide a contact number. It will only be shared with the comic</p>
         <input id="number" name="number" type="text" />
         <button id="submit" class="button">Submit</button>    
    </form>   
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("form").submit(function(){

        console.log("submit");
        $('#number').validate({
            rules: {
                  number : {
                    required: true
                    //customvalidation: true
                }                                        
            },
            messages: {
                number : {
                    required: "enter a phone number"                   
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                    // do other stuff for a valid form
                    //submit to parse

                    console.log("now validated");
                    var num = $('#number').val();
                    console.log("validated:" +' '+num);
            }     
        });

    });//closes submit

   $.validator.addMethod("customvalidation",
       function(value, element) {
               return (/^[A-Za-z\d=#$%@_]+$/.test(value));
       },
   "Sorry, no special characters allowed");
```

Comment: [You made the same programming mistakes three weeks ago.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18115160/594235)  [What was wrong with that answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18116262/594235)

Comment: Thank you sparky. That was a slightly different question that I didn't realize had been answered when I came to this particular problem in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.validate()` method is only the *initialization* of the plugin.  It never goes inside of a `submit()` handler.  Simply **attach it to your form** and call it *once* upon DOM ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').validate({
        .....
```

You will also need to change your form's `<button>` element into a `type="submit"`.

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/GJggc/1/

---

Please refer back to this answer on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18115160/594235), which also addresses the two JavaScript issues above along with a detailed explanation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18116262/594235

Answer (score 1):

> $('#number').validate

You have a bug. It is the FORM element which should be validated, not a form field.

```
<form id="youform">

....

$('#youform').validate
```